# Window Message to Send and recover Boolean and Integer

Tags: delphi, windows-messages

How can I Post a Windows message that contains a boolean and an integer. I do understand how to Post and Recover strings.
This is my code for strings.

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   LParam: string;
   WParam: string;
   pLParam: pChar;
   pWParam: pChar;
begin
   Memo.Clear;
   LParam := 'Now is the time for all good men...';
   Length(LParam);
   GetMem(pLParam, (Length(LParam) + 1) * SizeOf(Char));
   Move(LParam[1], pLParam^, (Length(LParam) + 1) * SizeOf(Char));

   WParam := 'This is the WParam. ';
   Length(WParam);
   GetMem(pWParam, (Length(WParam) + 1) * SizeOf(Char));
   Move(WParam[1], pWParam^, (Length(WParam) + 1) * SizeOf(Char));

   PostMessage(Handle, WM_SETPAUSE_MESSAGE, Integer(pWParam),Integer(pLParam));
end;
```

and this to recover the text...

```
procedure TForm5.WMsetPause(var MESSAGE: TMessage) { message WM_SETPAUSE_MESSAGE };
var
 pLParam: pChar;
 pWParam: pChar;
begin
 try
   pLParam := pChar(Message.LParam) ;
   Memo.Lines.Add( pLParam) ;
   Freemem(pLParam);
 except
   on E: Exception do
    Memo.Lines.Add(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.MESSAGE);
 end;

  try
   pWParam := pChar(Message.WParam);
   Memo.Lines.Add(pWParam);
   Freemem(pWParam);
  except
  on E: Exception do
   Memo.Lines.Add(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.MESSAGE);
  end;
 end;
```

Comment: You should check the returned by PostMessage in case the message cannot be posted. In that case destroy the memory. Your casts are wrong and will fail on 64 but code. Cast to LPARAM, WPARAM etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This task is much simpler than string sending.

You don't need to allocate memory for these types, because message parameters are already Integer, and Boolean needs just simple casting.

```
PostMessage(Handle, WM_MY_MESSAGE, IntegerParam, Integer(BooleanParam));
....
//in WM_MY_MESSAGE handler:
IntVar := Message.WParam;
BooleanVar := Boolean(Message.WParam);
```

Comment: Worked fine MBo except for the cast:
Ord(Message.WParam);
Had to be:
Boolean(Message.WParam)

Comment: Oh, yes, Ord is suitable for the first case (bool to int) :)